# Neat way of generating rectangle coordinates from two corner points?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I'm plotting a box in Matlab from four coordinates. Is there a neater way to generate these vectors than writing them out explicitly?

```
plot( ...
    [x_min x_max; x_min x_max; x_min x_min; x_max x_max], ...
    [y_min y_min; y_max y_max; y_min y_max; y_min y_max], ...
    '-r' );
```

In my case, the variables are called `lat_min` and `ax_min`, which means that the above lines won't fit into 80 characters. And I'd really like that, since
 I'm going to print the code.

Comment: I assume you also have `lat_max` and `ax_max` accordingly?

Comment: You could store them in a variable to cut down the characters per line? `Rl = [lat_min lat_max; lat_m...` and `plot(Rl, Ra, '-r')` ?

Comment: @EitanT Yes, of course :)

Comment: @Dan I could do that, but I don't consider that neat. I was hoping there's some ndgrid-like function that could do this, that I didn't know of.

Comment: You could call meshgrid twice (but that's worse imo)... or just encapsulate it in your own function / object.

Comment: how about using perms for all the permutations of possible coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [`rectangle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html):

```
pos = [ax_min, lat_min, ax_max - ax_min, lat_max - lat_min];
rectangle('Position', pos, 'EdgeColor', 'r')
```